# SQL SELECT group by one column and show nearest not found date

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, distinct

I have a table like this

```
ID  | DrugstoreName  | date       | city      | zipcode
1   | a1             | 2015-10-19 | paris 01  | 75001
2   | a2             | 2015-10-23 | paris 02  | 75002
3   | a3             | 2015-10-19 | paris 05  | 75005
4   | a4             | 2015-10-24 | marseille | 13000
5   | a5             | 2015-10-19 | nice      | 06000
6   | a6             | 2015-10-23 | paris 09  | 75009
7   | a7             | 2015-10-24 | paris 09  | 75009
8   | a8             | 2015-10-24 | paris 03  | 75003
9   | a9             | 2015-10-23 | paris 03  | 75003
10  | a10            | 2015-10-19 | paris 04  | 75004
```

What I am trying to do is to select distinct (city/zipcode) from my table, for which i don't have any matching records with at least one of certain dates (date1,date2,date3).

and if possible also show the nearest date for which we have no record.

for example i want to select distinct (city,zipcode, nearest-date-not-found) WHERE date doesn't match at least one of ("2015-10-23","2015-10-24");
the result should be:

```
paris 01   | 75001 | 2015-10-23
paris 02   | 75002 | 2015-10-24
paris 05   | 75005 | 2015-10-23
marseille  | 13000 | 2015-10-23
nice       | 06000 | 2015-10-23
paris 04   | 75004 | 2015-10-23
```

It's a bit complicated, and i know that i should think about redesigning my tables. but this is what I have for the moment, and i should deal with it.

Comment: Can you please add some sample data and the desired output? This will be helpful to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Show us some sample data and desire result

Comment: Question updated, thank you for your help.

Comment: Why is paris02 in expected list? It matches date 2015-10-23...  which is at least 1.... and marseille matches 10-24....

Comment: Where it doesn't match at least one of the given dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is you want dates for missing records.  So how do you select data from a database when data isn't present? We need to create those missing records in order for the database to return them as a value.

In the below example we do this by cross joining to a derived table (Y) which contains the dates you want to limit by. This could also be accomplished by using `SELECT Distinct date from Foo where date in ('2015-10-23','2015-10-24')` assuming records exist for those dates.  Then, by using aggregate functions, a distinct on dates and a having clause, we can generate the desired results.

An outer join would not work.  It wouldn't generate dates for each of the city/zips only a null record.  So this becomes a great time to understand cross join and why Cartesian products can help.

I used group_concat to show all missing dates and record dates. I did this so you could see why min(Y.date) returns the lowest date.

```
SELECT A.city, A.zipcode, min(Y.date) as Date, 
group_Concat(Y.Date) as AllMissingDates,
group_Concat(A.Date) as RecordDates
FROM foo A
CROSS JOIN 
 (SELECT '2015-10-23' date UNION ALL SELECT '2015-10-24') Y
WHERE A.Date <> Y.date
GROUP BY City, ZipCode
Having count(Distinct A.Date) < 2;
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ad3a/8/0)

```
**city      zipCode Date        AllMissingDates  RecordDates**
marseille   13000   2015-10-23  2015-10-23       2015-10-24
nice        6000    2015-10-23  2015-10-24,      2015-10-19,
                                2015-10-23       2015-10-19
paris 01    75001   2015-10-23  2015-10-23,      2015-10-19,
                                2015-10-24       2015-10-19
paris 02    75002   2015-10-24  2015-10-24       2015-10-23
paris 04    75004   2015-10-23  2015-10-24,      2015-10-19,
                                2015-10-23       2015-10-19
paris 05    75005   2015-10-23  2015-10-23,      2015-10-19,
                                2015-10-24       2015-10-19
```

Comment: Thank you but in this case you used date in ("2015-10-23","2015-10-24"), while what i needed was cities for which there is no record for one of the dates mentioned.

Comment: Wrote a fiddle to help me get the syntax right.

Comment: You are amazing, Thank you so much, works like a charm

Comment: one thing that i am still missing, how can i add multiple dates in the CROSS JOIN  (SELECT '2015-10-23' date UNION ALL SELECT '2015-10-24') ??

Comment: You add each date as a Union all select 'newdate' and you alter the having from a <2 to however many dates there are.

Comment: you are the best , thank you

Comment: note: if you can guarantee that each date is in the base table you can simply do a `select distinct date from tablename where date in (series)`, but you still also have to alter the `having count` to equal the number of dates in the series.